# GridView OnSelectedIndexChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the selected row of the `GridView`, and I know that I should be able to get that information based on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event. Whenever I click on the row, the event does not fire.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None"
  Width="930px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
  onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string company = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    Response.Redirect("Client_View.aspx", false);

}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. There is no code that I can see that resets its reference to another event, that I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a few years since this question was asked and I certainly hope the person with the problem got it figured out but I had the same problem and thanks to one of the responders I figured out what the problem was.

Check the actual button line in the Gridview and make sure that you have the  `CommandName="Select"` in the ButtonField. For some reason *that* code, which is normally entered automatically wasn't added.

Comment: What If I'm creating Select button from c#? like this gvSlots.SelectedIndexChanged += this.gvSlots_SelectedIndexChanged;
                gvSlots.AutoGenerateSelectButton = true; but still my SelectedIndexChanged not working

Answer (score 12):

If you are just clicking on the row in the `GridView`, that will not fire the event.  You have to have some kind of button in the row to click on, which will fire the `RowCommand` event, as well as the `SelectedIndexChanged` event (if the row you click is not already selected, of course).  It's not exactly like the Windows Forms DataGridView =)

The easiest way to get the event to fire, is to add this attribute to your `GridView` markup:

```
AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
```

This creates a "Select" `LinkButton`, which will fire the `Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged2` event in your code-behind when you click it.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, this is where you need to add that attribute:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" 
  Width="930px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"  
  onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2"
  AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" >
```

Answer (score 8):

It is NOT true that you can't click a row and have it handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. You just have to add a little code to the `RowCreated` event.

```
Protected Sub yourDataGrid_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles yourDataGrid.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me.yourDataGrid, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the 'onclick' script event is problematic and causes odd postbacks that do not make sense.  If it could be narrowed to an onchange it would be better, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

If you have postback code in selected index changing method you should false EnableEventValidation

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" MasterPageFile="~/Administration/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CourseStatusReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Administration_Reports_CourseStatusReport" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you need to wire up the custom event to the control.  Try something like this when first creating the control in the code-behind:

```
// Add event handler dynamically using C# syntax.
  GridView1.onselectedindexchanged += this.GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2;
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried looking at the key press event rather than SelectedIndexChanged event for gridviews.

Comment: No I have not. I was under the impression that the selectedindexchange event was all that I needed to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Enable selection as suggested by `@jadarmel27`. Try event initialization

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged += this.GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this bug/error on one of my ASPX forms in Visual Studio 2022 where debugger was unable to hit the fired event. According to my experience, this strange behavior is displayed when you copy markup/code from other files. Particular controls with events attached to them cause this issue.

Steps I took (several time):

- I re-examine the markup and code.
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Delete data from temp and .vs folders
- Clean and rebuild project

Finally, I created a new form and added the controls markup manually.
That's worked.