# How to use Session to save value on current row of GridView, to be copied into TextBox? - VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to use `Session` to record the data of the 1st column of current row to be used in another Web From which will be opened using a `LinkButton` that is in the `GridView`.

Basically, if I click the `LinkButton` on the 1st row, the 1st column data of the 1st row will be copied to the next Web Form. But before I do that, I want to do a smaller scale experiment to test it. So instead for now I want the `Session` to copy the data into a `TextBox` in the same form.

For reference, here is the design of the `GridView`, most rows removed since they're not relevant:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Arial">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#B7DBFF" />
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="caseticket" HeaderText="Ticket #" >
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000066" ForeColor="White" Wrap="False" width="10%"/>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:BoundField>
                                                                
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000066" ForeColor="White" Wrap="False" width="10%"/>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="newLog" runat="server" onclick = "CaseLog_click" >Add Log </asp:linkbutton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000066" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>
```

For the `TemplateField` is a `LinkButton` with a `onclick` property. With it, I created the sub:

```
Sub CaseLog_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Session("ticket") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
    'Response.Redirect("~/CaseLog.aspx")  ==> will be using this to proceed to next Web Form
    TextBox1.Text = Session("ticket")    '==> For test use only.

End Sub
```

If I only kept the `Response.Redirect("~/CaseLog.aspx")` in the sub, the `LinkButton` can direct me to the next Web Form. But as it is now, during testing when I use the `LinkButton` I get an error on the `session` line of the sub.

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Is the code salvageable, or do  I need to redo this?

Thanks.

Comment: The cells collection starts at 0, so first column would be 0, not 1. I would perhaps assign the value to a variable, and put in a break point in the debugger to ensure you have the value from the grid. You really needed two separate questions here. How to get/grab a value from a grid, and THEN start code (and maybe a question) about how to pass the value into the next form (session() is a good idea). And your test/debug code of a text box you have? (again, great idea - try with cell(0), and see if that works. If that works, then you are quite much home free.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I changed cell to 0 but still have the same issue. Like I said on the question the GridView was changed in the post to remove irrelevant columns. So if the cell was 1 there would still be a value. Also the data from the GridView was obtained from SQL query in a load event. Could that be a factor?

Comment: filling with data - not an issue - see my post below - the GridView selected index event can be used (not a event code stub for the actual button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the button event to select the row is not wired up.

I would use say this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select"  HeaderText="Select" ShowHeader="True" Text="Button" />
```

Note CAREFULL how we put the CommandName="Select" in above. If you don't do this, then the selected row does not come though correctly to the click event you have.

You could try the select command as per above on your link button, but I would just use the above. Now, hightlight the grid in the  form desinger. On the properity sheet, go to events, and double click on the SelectedIndex Change event. So, your buttion is not changing the selected index correctly.

The code stub will look like this:

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim lgridrow As GridViewRow = Me.GridView1.SelectedRow

    Debug.Print("<" & lgridrow.Cells(0).Text & ">")
    Debug.Print("<" & lgridrow.Cells(3).Text & ">")

    Debug.Print("<" & Me.GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text & ">")


End Sub
```

Note VERY careful how the event code stub is setup - the event args are different then yours.
So, you can try the CommandName="Select" in your existing code, but if not, then try the above button field as opposed to your custom asp.net button you have. As it stands, it don't look like your asp.net button is firing the row-changed event.

***Edit and follow up:***

Can I have extra buttons - run their own code?

Yes, you can. You can do this several ways (one is to  pick up  which button was clicked in the SelectedIndex change event.

Or, you can drop in extra buttons and use that event code stub.

So, in my example, lets add  an extra button.

we now have this:

```
       <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select"  HeaderText="Select" ShowHeader="True" Text="Button" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"   OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
                        CommandName="MySelect" CommandArgument  ="<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>"
                        style="background-color:gray;color:white;text-decoration:none;padding-left:6px;padding-right:6px"
                        text="Mybutton"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

We thus have this:

[image]

Now, we can attach/have button code for the extra button. But NOTE careful we did NOT use the built  in SELECT for the command argument. The REASON is that if we have  Command=select, then the selected index WILL fire, but AFTER our button code stub. That means we cannot use the selectedrow (too early).

So, what we do/did in above was have the CommandArguemnt PASS the selected  row value - that value will pass ok, and thus we don't care that the selected index event does not fire (and by CHANGING our command argument to NOT "select", then in fact the selectedindexchange event DOES NOT fire.

As a result, we use the passed row in the command argument, and we have this for the button code:

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ixrow As Integer = sender.CommandArgument

    Debug.Print(Me.GridView1.Rows(ixrow).Cells(0).Text)

End Sub
```

And note while we are editing the markup, intel-sense will give a list of options when editing. Eg this:

[image]

So, that gives us a chance to wire up (add) a standard click event). No selected index code stub is required (since the button would fire before selected index anyway). So we are now manually wiring up this event. We are NOT thus using the selectedindex change event - we don't even need it.

So, now in our button stub, we are free to do anything we want - including jumping to another page

eg:

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ixrow As Integer = sender.CommandArgument

    Debug.Print(Me.GridView1.Rows(ixrow).Cells(0).Text)
    Session("HotelName") = Me.GridView1.Rows(ixrow).Cells(3)
    Response.Redirect("~/ShowHotelDetails.aspx")

End Sub
```

So, to add separate code buttons:
Don't use selected index change event - you MIGHT still want it  to run but it will run/fire AFTER your button code (so can't  use selectedrow - too early).

But, you do need Command="myjunk" because without a command, then the command argument does not work. By passing the row index in commandargument, then we are free to grab data from the gridview as per above code via row index.

So, you can well dump the selected index change event. You just have to pass the row index, and work from that. The code stub can thus walk the dog, setup values in session, or even pass/make the url with parameters.

Comment: I don't quite understand here... I changed the `TemplateField` into a `ButtonField`  and used the `SelectedIndexChanged` sub like your answer, and I commented out my sub temporarily. Testing the button gets no result... I even change from your debug to my textbox and still nothing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does the code stub run? Note how the event is not really the  button anymore, but the gridview index change  event. Also, do add the Command="Select"

Comment: I added the `CommandName` in the `ButtonField` properties. I just renamed it as `"CaseAdd"`. I placed a breakpoint in the `SelectedIndexChanged` sub and run the program. Clicking the button doesn't trigger the breakpoint. I believe its because the sub didn't refer to the `CommandName` but I'm not too sure where to implant it.

Comment: CommandName is set in stone - you can't change that value. it has to be Select. Read this post:

Comment: Read this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166568/gridview-onselectedindexchanged-event-not-firing. You can double click on the property sheet (on selected index change) to let vs create the event for you.

Comment: OK. Didn't realize CommandName is fixed. Now Output shows the value. I'll try to link to next form and see then. And it works. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to have 2 button fields with the same `CommandName`? Now I have another button to take me to a 3rd Web Form but I don't know how to put it into the event sub.

Comment: You can add many buttons - each having their own code run. See my "edit" to above post - I explain how to do this. This suggests you dump use of selectedIndexChanged event.